# DIY battery Pack Cell amperage difference

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, lithium-ion, diy

I have individually tested the capacity of ten 18650 batteries with my iCharger 4010. My question is, how much ampacity difference is ok when packing them in parallel ? The following are the readings from my batteries. I was thinking arraigning as below:

1. 1970mAh
2. 1876mAh
3. 1796mAh
4. 1783mAh
5. 1635mAh
6. 1596mAh
7. 1497mAh
8. 1457mAh
9. 1158mAh
10. 800mAh

Will test the 800mAh again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When wiring cells in parallel it doesn't matter what their individual capacities are, since they will be at the same voltage and so will charge and discharge together.

Matching capacities is more important when wiring cells in *series*, because the same charge goes through each cell so if one has lower capacity then it will charge and discharge faster. Lithium cells will be damaged (possibly leading to a fire) if the voltage goes too high or low due to over charge/discharge, and the charger may not be able to detect the over/under voltage of a single cell in the pack.

Another reason for measuring capacity before making up a pack is to check that the cells are in good health. 10% below nominal capacity may be normal manufacturing tolerance, but 30% is bad. At least 2 of your cells appear to be faulty, and another 4 are suspicious.

Comment: Thanks Bruce. So the set of batteries in series should be good ones and it doesn't matter when the others are connected in parallel for the increase in amps. I am guessing the last two would be faulty. Anyways i will be testing them all again individually.

Comment: "So the set of batteries in series should be good ones" - not sure what you mean by that. If your batteries each have several cells in series than you should check the individual cell voltages in each (battery) pack to make sure they are the same (<0.05V difference when charged).

Comment: Well good ones i meant the batteries that are connected in series should be best in the pack as those determine the total voltage of the pack. I did not get the part "difference when charged". Does that mean the difference between the  cells ?

Comment: yes, difference between the cells. "the batteries that are connected in series should be best in the pack as those determine the total voltage of the pack" - ???

Comment: You said the batteries should be in good health and since max voltage comes from those connected in series and those bad cells could affect it. Was i wrong with that assumption. Which cells are bad that you've noticed?

Comment: In a series pack the cell capacities need to be matched as closely as possible. Total capacity is equal to the lowest capacity cell, so you wouldn't put an 800mA or 1158mA cell in series with 1700~1900mA cells as it would be wasting the capacity of the better cells. But you also have to consider _why_ some cells have much lower capacity than others - most likely they are poorly manufactured or defective.